# Executing new task based on sigchld() from previous task

Tags: c++, shell, fork, signals, process-management

I'm currently in the process of building a small shell within C++.

A user may enter a job at the prompt such as `exe1 && exe2 &`. Similar to the BASH shell, I will only execute `exe2` if `exe1` exits successfully. In addition, the entire job must be performed in the background (as specified by the trailing `&` operator).

Right now, I have a `jobManager` which handles execution of jobs and a `job` structure which contains the job's executable and their individual arguments / conditions. A job is started by calling `fork()` and then calling `execvp()` with the proper arguments. When a job ends, I have a signal handler for `SIGCHLD`, in which I perform `wait()` to determine which process has just ended. When `exe1` ends, I observe its exit code and make a determination as to whether I should proceed to launch `exe2`.

My concern is how do I launch `exe2`. I am concerned that if I use my jobManager start function from the context of my `SIGCHLD` handler, I could end up with too many `SIGCHLD` handler functions hanging out on the stack (if there were 10 conditional executions, for instance). In addition, it just doesn't seem like a good idea to be starting the next execution from the signal handler, even if it is occurring indirectly. (I tried doing something similar 1.5 years ago when I was just learning about signal handling -- I seem to recall it failing on me).

All of the above needs to be able to occur in the background and I want to avoid having the `jobManager` sitting in a busy wait just waiting for `exe1` to return. I would also prefer to not have a separate thread sitting around just waiting to start the execution of another process. However, instructing my `jobManager` to begin execution of the next process from the `SIGCHLD` handler seems like poor code.

Any feedback is appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two ways:
1)Replace you sighandler with loop that call "sigwait" (see man 3 sigwait)
then in loop

2)before start create pipe, and in mainloop of your program use "select" on pipe handle to wait
events. In signal handler write to pipe, and in mainloop handle situation.

Comment: Ah -- your select() solution is very interesting to me. I've used select() / poll() in sockets programming and was hoping to do something similar here to avoid a busy wait. However, I'm guessing the pipe would need to be 'global' as I cannot provide anything to the signal handler at runtime.

Comment: sigwait loops are ugly, and don't do much good here because they need to be background jobs.

Comment: You can handle this wihtout global variables, but in linux specific way: signalfd create descriptor for you to get information about signals.

Comment: Yep -- looked into signalfd more -- you were right. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm that's a good one.

What about forking twice, once per process? The first one runs, and the second one stops. In the parent SIGCHLD handler, send a SIGCONT to the second child, if appropriate, which then goes off and runs the job. Naturally, you SIGKILL the second one if the first one shouldn't run, which should be safe because you won't really have set anything up.

How does that sound? You'll have a process sitting around doing nothing, but it shouldn't be for very long.

Comment: Only reason I would like to avoid this solution is because it seems like an unfortunate waste of resources from my perspective. There are also more advanced situations which I want to be able to handle, such as for() loops within the job.

Comment: @BSchlinker It's not really a waste of resources, unless your child processes are doing a lot. fork() is copy-on-write, so maybe a KB or so is used by the waiting process - and no CPU time, since it'd be blocked.